# How do you protect a private area for a single page app in Vue? (Best Practice)

Tags: vuejs2, jwt, vue-router

I'm new to Vue and SPAs so maybe this is a simple question... To restrict access to certain pages in Vue I'm using the following code. It uses meta data in the route definition to explicitly allow access to a page:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      const isNotFound = to.matched.some(record => record.path == "*")
      if (isNotFound) {    
        return next()
      }
      else {
          const isPublic = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.public)
          const onlyWhenLoggedOut = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.onlyWhenLoggedOut)
          const loggedIn = !!TokenService.getToken()
    
          if (!isPublic && !loggedIn) {
            return next({
              path:'/login',
              query: {redirect: to.fullPath}  // Store the full path to redirect the user to after login
            })
          }
    
    
         next()

      } //else
} // router.beforeEach
```

In the above case I'm getting and testing a token from a TokenService. My backend API is protected with the JWT so I'm not worried about exposing data, but in a client side SPA it doesn't seem possible to *absolutely* protect a page. (In the above case I simply need to inject `true` in my if statement.

What is the best practice for securing a page client side? Am I doing this wrong?